# How does a regular expression match non-repeating substrings in a string?

Tags: java, regex

There is a string:

```
"1112344866893334".
```

I want to use regular expressions to match non-repeating substrings like:

```
"23", "8", "89", "4".
```

How can I do that?

Comment: First of all, you can't do that only with regexp, because you should check is there any yet before a new combination. You should create some algorithm of checking and after that only make substring with regexp

Comment: @Dred [it is possible](https://regex101.com/r/iS6tKb/1) with less restrictive regex engines though.

Comment: @FrankPuffer it's not a duplicate as the other question asks for matching whole strings while this question asks to match the substrings.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the length of the string, and then use a regular expression to assert that the substring does not repeat, e.g.

```
String input = "1112344866893334";
for (int i=0; i < input.length()-1; ++i) {
    String substring = input.substring(i, i+2);
    String regex = "(?!.*" + substring + ".*" + substring + ").*";
    if (input.matches(regex)) {
        System.out.println("matching substring: " + substring);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as long as you can tolerate empty matches:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String[] items = "1112344866893334".split("(\\d)\\1+");
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(items));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified my earlier answer to include some special cases.

These include:

- string begins with repeating digits (e.g. 111.....)
- empty string
- string contains only repeating digits (e.g. 1122334455 )
- series of different repeating digits (e.g. 11122233365...)
- series of different repeats within string (e.g. 4311122233398)

```
      String[] testCases = {
            "2111222333594454555", "333555666540922229789", "", "54", "111",
            "111222333"
      };
      for (String s : testCases) {
         String[] ss = s.replaceAll("(\\d)\\1+", "AA")
                        .replaceAll("^[A]+", "")
                        .split("[A]+");
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ss));
      }
   }
```

The first replaceAll replaces all occurrences of repeating digits with AA.
The second one deletes repeating A's from beginning of string.
The split splits on repeated A's.